# FlexBox CSS and alignment

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm learning Flex and here is my template :

```
<div id="container">
    <div>person1.name</div>
    <div>person1.address</div>
    <div>person1.phone</div>
    <div>person1.email</div>
    <div>person1.hobbies</div>
    <div>person2.name</div>
    <div>person2.address</div>
    <div>person2.phone</div>
    <div>person2.email</div>
    <div>person2.hobbies</div>
</div>
```

I would like something like this (for my HTML rendering) : everything that is specific to person1 is on the left, and everything that is specific to person2 on the right.

```
person1.name       person2.name
person1.address    personé.address
person1.phone      person2.phone
person1.email      person2.email
person1.hobbies    person2.hobbies
```

Any idea using FlexBox ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is my speculative answer if there are more than 2 people and a field like hobbies goes past 1 line.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.person {
  flex: 0 1 300px;
}
.
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="person">
    <div>person1.name</div>
    <div>person1.address</div>
    <div>person1.phone</div>
    <div>person1.email</div>
    <div>person1.hobbies</div>
  </div>
  <div class="person">
    <div>person2.name</div>
    <div>person2.address</div>
    <div>person2.phone</div>
    <div>person2.email</div>
    <div>person2.hobbies soccer, collecting stamps, jogging, video games, tv, cooking, reading</div>
  </div>
  <div class="person">
    <div>person3.name</div>
    <div>person3.address</div>
    <div>person3.phone</div>
    <div>person3.email</div>
    <div>person3.hobbies</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 I was about to post exact same approach with a stmt "I'll personally prefer wrapping individual person's details in separate `div` so that I get more flexibility with the positioning.".. after finishing my dinner... thanks you did.

Comment: Did it for you and your comment @VivekAthalye :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container {
  display:  inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100px;
}

#container > div {
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>person1.name</div>
  <div>person1.address</div>
  <div>person1.phone</div>
  <div>person1.email</div>
  <div>person1.hobbies</div>
  <div>person2.name</div>
  <div>person2.address</div>
  <div>person2.phone</div>
  <div>person2.email</div>
  <div>person2.hobbies</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will not work if any of the 'template' fields have multiple lines ... like address and hobbies

Comment: @VivekAthalye, you are speculating. If there are any other requirements, they should be posted in the question. I provided an answer based on the information provided.

Comment: Yet you speculate the container has a height of 100px

Comment: @StefanBob. Not sure what you're talking about. I provided a straight answer to the question. My answer solves the problem that is presented. Anything beyond that is speculation. I don't think my answer warranted a downvote, but at least you commented. (If you down-voted me because you think I down-voted you, keep in mind that there are more than 2 people on this site.)

Comment: @Michael_B I just agree with Vivek, this answer isn't useful in the very common case where the lines for fields like hobbies and address would spill over 1 line. Or I guess extend the page to an unreasonable amount

Comment: @StefanBob, if that was the actual problem presented in the question, I would have posted a different answer. I don't know all the requirements in this case. So I didn't speculate.

Comment: @Michael_B Of that I have no doubt. For someone learning flexbox and who clearly isn't listing every facet of the problem, I believe we can infer his intention just from the fact that he is using variable interpolation, the data could be longer. That's all. Yes you technically are nailing every requirement of his question. Great.